# Count how many times a record appears

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a query which has a column, `schloc`

```
schloc

TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
NOTEST
NOTEST
NOTEST
NOTEST
RANDOM
RANDOM
RANDOM
RANDOM
```

I want to put it in a table in my SSRS report like this:

```
TEST     NOTEST     RANDOM
4        4          4
```

How can I use the COUNT for my expression to get the count?

I tried to add this: `=SUM(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Completed.Value),0,1))` but it didn't yield anything in the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, if there is a discrete list of options that isn't going to change:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!shloc.Value="Test", 1,0))
```

Otherwise, you'll want to do something like a PIVOT in the SQL query in your dataset, or possibly custom VB.

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to use GroupBy to get the count :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable GROUP BY schloc
```

Comment: I don't think I can input SELECT into a expression window.

Comment: My bad i read the question to fast. I touthg it was a SQL query!